# Createcapture session always failed for some devices in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camera, android-camera2

I am trying to capture video in my android Kotlin app. But it is not working as expected and always showing the failed message. How to fix this failed issue

```
  mCameraDevice!!.createCaptureSession(
                surfaces,
                object : CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback() {
                    override fun onConfigured(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession) 
                    { 
                     Toast.makeText(activity, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                     }
                     override fun onConfigureFailed(cameraCaptureSession: CameraCaptureSession) {             
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```